# How to customize sphinx.ext.autosummary rst template?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

[Here](http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/ext/autosummary.html#customizing-templates) in Sphinx's documentation it is said what those templates can be redefined.
So I tried to copy `module.rst` from `/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autosummary` to `source/_templates/autosummary` (also tried just `source/_templates`) with some slight changes. But after I regenerated the docs nothing changed.

Maybe i should add some specific option to `.. autosummary::` tag to specify custom template directory? (in conf.py directory is set right and sphinx see `html` templates as well)

UPD: source code: https://github.com/actionless/wooper/blob/master/docs.sh

Comment: The link to the source code is broken.

Comment: @gerrit, yup it was 4 years ago, documentation structure changed from that moment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should work if you do the following:

1. Ensure that the value of the `templates_path` configuration variable is set to `['_templates']` in conf py.
2. Put the custom template in the `_templates` subdirectory.
3. Use the [`:template:`](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autosummary.html#directive-autosummary)  option:

   ```
   .. autosummary::
     :template: mytemplate.rst
   ```

Comment: are you sure what no any additional actions are needed?
i did it all the same, but it seems what contents of '_templates' directory is processed like source files (and sphinx-build complains about it like about wrong source). adding it to exclude-pattern mutes those warnings but 'autosummary' still behaves like no ":template:" parameter specifiede

Comment: btw, here is the source code: https://github.com/actionless/wooper/blob/debug-autosummary/docs.sh

Comment: As far as I can tell, you are not generating "stub" pages as described at http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autosummary.html?highlight=stub. In that case, there are no templates that can be customized.

Comment: so seems i need to add `autosummary_generate` option to make things work?

Answer (score 0):

*Edited*: I've originally posted an answer to the wrong issue here. However, might help as well here.

- [Sphinx autosummary: How to remove automember for __init__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67899730/)

One can 'overrule' the default templates by adding a custom file into the `_templates` folder. E.g., if you want to change the template for classes used when calling the autosummary directive create a custom `class.rst` file under this path:

- `_templates/autosummary/class.rst`

Should be taken automatically without the need of specifying `:template:` explicitly.

Comment: Shouldn't this be an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/67899730/407651?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Got confused with too many browser taps *ups*. Adjusted my wrong post here as it might also for this post.