# Sphinx autosummary: How to remove automember for __init__

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

**Problem**

I am using `sphinx.ext.autosummary` for my python package. The problem is that `.. autosummary::` adds `.. automethod:: __init__` at all times, even if undocumented.

In the mean time I have found various ways to include it a third time (as a special member) or included it in the methods; but not how I can get rid of `.. automethod:: __init__`.

[image: rst creted by .. autosummary:: (left), rendered HTML documentation (right).]

As shown this simply duplicates the class specification above and has no use at all. I could, of course, create all `*.rst`s by hand but that is not an option and would make autosummary somewhat obsolete. In addition it creates warnings due to `duplicate object description` (`__init__` is in methods as well which is fine).

**System**

- `python 3.8.5`
- `sphinx-build 4.0.2` (w/ bootstrap theme)

Does anyone have the golden hint I am searching for since hours? :)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at the conf.py config values?  I'm guessing at your setup a bit but I think this might help: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autoclass_content

Comment: Thanks @morric for the fast reply. I've tested this in all variations, unfortunately `autoclas_content` seems to have no effect on the output of `.. autosummary::`.

Comment: You can customize the template (class.rst) that is used to generate the "stub" .rst page. See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autosummary.html#customizing-templates and   https://stackoverflow.com/q/28147432/407651

Comment: Thanks a lot! Added a possible solution to the original post above.

Answer (score 1):

---

**Solution**

In the `templates_path` (see `conf.py`; typically `"_templates"`) create a folder `autosummary`. Search for the default `class.rst`, copy it into the new folder (`_templates/autosummary/class.rst`) and adjust the template to your needs. Nothing else required.

**My adjustments to `class.rst`**

- After `.. autoclass:: {{ objname }}` adding `:noindex:`.
- Removed line `.. automethod:: __init__`.
- Need to figure out if `:noindex:` as default is a good idea.

Many thanks to @mzjn, that was the hint I missed; saved my day!

Comment: Where can I find the default class.rst?

Comment: @AstralCai Run `import sphinx.ext.autosummary` and look at `sphinx.ext.autosummary.__file__`. That will tell you the install folder. On my machine its something like `/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autosummary/__init__.py`. In the `autosummary` folder, there will be a path `templates/autosummary` which has the default `base.rst`, `class.rst` and `module.rst` templates